# dot_module and dot_dot_module when import module

Tags: python, import

I see many people use the following import methods in their projects:

```
from .module1 import a,b
from ..module2 import *
```

The module1 and module2 are a `.py` file but not a folder for package. What's the differences to the `import module`? Does it mean to import the module in current and ../ folder? But when I try to import another file in same folder, it said:

```
import .other
>>> SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
from .other import *
>>> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I'm curious on it. Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is *relative imports*. They allow you to import modules by specifying their relative paths, without hard-coding the name of the package in which the modules are defined.

> Does it mean to import the module in current and ../ folder?

Yes.

See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more details. Note it says:

> Relative imports must always use `from <> import`; `import <>` is always
>   absolute.

which is why you get the `SyntaxError` when trying `import .foo`.

The `ValueError` is probably because you are running the importing file as a script (and it used to confuse me a lot). You need to run it as a package (using the `-m` switch) for relative imports to work. That is, suppose `foo.py` relative-imports other modules, you can't run it by

```
$ python foo.py  # non-package error
```

Instead you do

```
$ python -m foo
```

See the related question: [How to do relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).

Comment: Thanks~ I'm the first time to know `relative import`. I tried the test in the interpreter using `import a` which contains `from .other import *`. So it's not the `__main__` in this situation. Also I try the `python -m a` even a new script b (containing `import a`) for `python -m b`. It still raises the same ValueError...

Comment: @platinhom Can you lay out your directory structure in OP?

Comment: The directory structure is : a.py, b.py, and other.py are all in the same folder. I add a __init__.py in this folder to make it looks like a package. But run the b.py (`import a`) still don't work. But, when I move the b.py to upper folder (`b.py`, `test/a.py`, `test/other.py`, `test/__init__.py`) and modify b.py to `import test.a`, the `from other import *` works! It seems like that it's necessary to make `a.py` as a module in a package.

Comment: @platinhom  That's right, the file you run must be inside a package (as `-m` should make clear). BTW, if you are on Python 3, `__init__.py` is not necessary for declaring a package, although some people like to have it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I am still a little confused with their concepts but I will further check it~